# cannot map json data to js model

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am trying to map 2 similar incoming json into one JS model, **the first incoming json gets mapped correctly** and the second json fails.

here's the code

```
let allInstruments: Instrument[] = [];
      try {
        if (equityInstruments.constructor === Array) {
          equityInstruments.forEach(element => {

            let instrument: Instrument = element;           
            allInstruments.push(instrument);
          });
        } 
        console.log(allInstruments.length + ' after equity processing');
        if (mutualInstruments.constructor === Array) {
          mutualInstruments.forEach(
            element => {

            let instrument = new Instrument(element.wdId.S, element.amcCode.S, element.schemeName.S);
            allInstruments.push(instrument);
          });
        } 
        console.log(allInstruments.length + ' after mutual processing');
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
```

The above code handles 2 incoming json, and below is the model where it needs to be mapped but I get error saying

```
Cannot set property 'S' of undefined
```

Instrument Model:

```
export class Instrument {

    wdId: { S: string };
    description: { S: string };
    symbol: { S: string };

    public constructor(wdId: string, symbol: string, description: string) {
        this.wdId.S = wdId; //Cannot refer to this.wdId - Error is thrown here, when mutualInstrument is getting mapped
        this.symbol.S = symbol;
        this.description.S = description;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export class Instrument {

      wdId = { S: 'null' };
      description = { S: 'null' };
      symbol = { S: 'null' };

      public constructor(wdId: string, symbol: string, description: string) {
          this.wdId.S = wdId;
          this.symbol.S = symbol;
          this.description.S = description;
      }
  }
```

You'll call `var inst1 = new Instrument('wdId_A', 'symbol_A', 'desc_A')`
to create a class object

Hope this helped

---EDIT---

you can also do this:

```js
export class Instrument {
  wdId: { S: string };
  description: { S: string };
  symbol: { S: string };

  public constructor(wdId: string, symbol: string, description: string) {
    this.wdId = {S: wdId};
    this.symbol = {S: symbol};
    this.description = {S: description};
  }
}
```

;)

Comment: Thanx Luca, can you please explain why it was required to initialize like this?

Comment: You're welcome! yes, it's because you are referring to `S` property of a `WdId` that in the constructor is still `undefined`. You could have `wdId: Object;` and in the constructor `this.WdId = oneObj`, so there won't be problems, because you are referring to an `undefined` object INSTANTIATING it.. The real error is to refer to `S` property before the constructor knows what `WdId` is

Comment: EDITED answer to be more specific! ;)